# Clearing the screen in c++

Tags: c++, macos

Is their a way to clear the screen in c++ on a mac without using the 
    system("clear"); 
command? If not is their a way to replace a character?

Comment: By "screen" you mean a terminal (emulator)?

Comment: http://rlv.zcache.com/there_their_and_theyre_tshirt-p235250795253403358z8nr2_400.jpg

Comment: You can write a bunch of newlines and that will clear the screen

Comment: @SethCarnegie: What if you have a really big screen?   With... 10k+ lines?

Comment: @bovjac: Keep in mind, many programs write to a file instead of a screen.  What would that look like for a file?

Comment: @MooingDuck what screen has 10k lines? And that's basically what `clear` does anyway

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you absolutely do not care about portability, just emit the same sequence of characters that `clear` does.

```
$ clear | od -c
0000000 033   [   H 033   [   2   J
0000007
$ : "Oh, it is ESCAPE [ H ESCAPE [ 2 J on my computer"
$ cat clear_fun.cc
#include <iostream>
void clear() { std::cout << "\033[H\033[2J" << std::flush; }
$
```

Comment: o I am sorry I understand that you were never new and never had questions like this so you fluff your chest at newbies looking to learn.

Comment: This is not a stupid question at all. @ bovjac: You will face such comments from some SO members. But there is nothing like a stupid question. Whichever question you ask, "Frame it well". +1 for the question.

Answer (score 1):

Standard C++ doesn't talk about a "screen" or something. On UNIXes you can use ncurses. Generally, this just use terminal control codes. Mostly, you can assume that VT100 is the terminal and you can just use the various control codes. How to do it on Windows terminals I don't know.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Windows_and_DOS "Console windows in all versions of Windows do not support ANSI escape sequences at all."  Windows does have special commands for this sort of thing somewhere though.